# Using Random Forest Probabilities for customer sensitivity

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, data-mining, probability

I am trying to build out a customer sensitivity model to price increase. My hypothesis is that as "Annual Fee" to a product subscription increases so will the probability of a customer to churn.

I am planning to initially build out a classifier model with output as 0 - (Does not churn) and 1 (Churn). For each percent increase in annual fee the probability of churn should also increase. Can I use a classifiers proba function for this kind of analysis?

**For eg: If a customer is given 5% increase and the output of classifier is 1 and probability is 60% then for my next data point, keeping everything constant and just changing the increase from 5% to 10%, I want to see that output of the classifier is again 1 but has a higher probability (higher than 60%)**

I will really appreciate any help input on this!

Comment: Yes. This is called _calibration_ and [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/calibration.html) is a calibration plot of various classifiers, including RF. Welcome to the site!

Comment: This is not at all related to calibration or ROC curves as the x axis has a completely different meaning. In the OP, it is an input variable. +1 for the question. You can certainly apply the random forest like this. During fitting, you might even want to impose a monotonicity constraint, so that increasing the annual fee will never be associated with a lower churn probability, all other inputs being constant. Some implementations offer this option.

Comment: The OP wants accurate probability estimates, and calibration is how that is achieved. Calibration is not just about creating a plot. I agree with your suggestion to impose monotonicity, but implementing it might be a challenge.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But is there any link on how I can implement monotonicity?